# Foreach preg_match_all

Tags: php, array, regex, foreach

Preciso montar uma array com todos os dados vindos de outra array usando o preg_match_all,estou utilizando o seguinte código.

```
$results = array(
        'nome;26484865464864;ruadarua;desmontagem;sim;matogrosso;liberado',
        'fulanodetal;26469865464865;avenidadocentro;desmontagem;sim;matogrosso;liberado',
        'ciclano;26464065464866;ruasaojosegenonimo;desmontagem;sim;matogrosso;liberado'
    );

    foreach ($results as $value) {
        $cnpj_desmontagem[] = preg_match_all('/(\d{14})/', $value, $cnpj_desmontagem);
    }

    var_dump($cnpj_desmontagem);
```

Porém ele está sobrepondo os outros valores ao invés de montar uma array com todos os dados colhidos

Comment: Não é essa a saida? https://ideone.com/eZ6KbV

Comment: não, caso eu pare o forech no meio com um die ele me mostra os outros valores, o problema é que os valores atribuidos estão se sobrepondo ao invés de montar a array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_match_all()` retorna se o elemento procurado foi achado, a captura fica no terceiro argumento. Pode simplicar essa regex removendo o grupo `( )` e crie uma nova variável para armazenar os demais valores.

```
$results = array(
        'nome;26484865464864;ruadarua;desmontagem;sim;matogrosso;liberado',
        'fulanodetal;26469865464865;avenidadocentro;desmontagem;sim;matogrosso;liberado',
        'ciclano;26464065464866;ruasaojosegenonimo;desmontagem;sim;matogrosso;liberado'
    );

    $cnpjs = [];
    foreach ($results as $value) {
         if(preg_match_all('/\d{14}/m', $value, $m)) $cnpjs[] = $m[0][0];
    }

    print_r($cnpjs);
```

Saida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 26484865464864
    [1] => 26469865464865
    [2] => 26464065464866
)
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado, eu estava confundindo a maneira de retornar e não dei atenção ao terceiro parametro.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia,

Esta função retorna um inteiro, 0 se não foi encontrado, 1 se for apenas uma ocorrencia etc

Sendo assim tenta fazer desta forma

```
$results = array(
    'nome;26484865464864;ruadarua;desmontagem;sim;matogrosso;liberado',
    'fulanodetal;26469865464865;avenidadocentro;desmontagem;sim;matogrosso;liberado',
    'ciclano;26464065464866;ruasaojosegenonimo;desmontagem;sim;matogrosso;liberado'
);

foreach ($results as $value) {
    if (preg_match_all('/(\d{14})/', $value, $cnpj_desmontagem) > 0) {
        $cnpj_desmontagem[] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($cnpj_desmontagem);
```

http://www.devfuria.com.br/php/o-basico-sobre-a-funcao-preg-match-all/

Comment: `array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "26464065464866"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "26464065464866"
  ]
  2 => "ciclano;26464065464866;ruasaojosegenonimo;desmontagem;sim;matogrosso;liberado"
]    `                                                                                                                                   
 Ele ainda me retorna apenas o ultimo valor e também desta vez ele me retorna a array inteira, eu precisava limpar ela para apenas coletar os CNPJs.